# Disputed Answer - Demo Link Removed

Tags: support, edits

I had [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45745624/) modified which removed a demonstration link (I think because it contained information the OP wasn't suppose to share publicly). Is there a way to see where the dispute is/was? The link on the question just pointed to the root meta site.

I was going to provide a functional demo with the redacted data because of a comment the OP made prior to it being locked.

The history of the question also still has the link with the private data so I'm not sure if there is a better way to have that edited.

Comment: Your answer was unlocked a while back. The link you provided has been removed, and all references to it/some things in the original question have been redacted. Feel free to go ahead and put a new link if it adds value.

Comment: @JonClements Was there another thread about it or just flagged with a comment? (You unlocked it 1 hour ago, prior to that it was locked for 4 days). Okay, I'll add an example with sample data.

Comment: Not another thread that I'm aware of - it just came to moderator attention the way things do.

Comment: @JonClements Okay, thanks. I'll just delete this now or is there some place I should mark this as resolved?

Comment: Umm... it's a fairly one off thing related to a specific post for only a short period. Up to you - but it's not going to cause issues if you choose to remove it but it's not going to be of a massive amount of value in the future to others if left...